# JNI callback to Java

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Need some help in understanding when the java string is deleted. On the c side the string is deleted after the call to onCandidates and on the java side setRemoteDescription may take some time to process sdp. How does java sync up to the c side and would it be normal to make a copy of the string before proceeding.

**C source code**

```
jstring jstrBuf = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, sdp);
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, onCandidatesCallbackObj, onCandidatesCallback, jstrBuf);
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jstrBuf);
```

**java code**

```
private void onCandidates(String sdp) {
  setRemoteDescription(sdp); // may take time?
}
```

My code works most of the time but some times my app crashes. Initially this was due to a different thread on the c side. I think my solution is working correctly so now I am considering the life time of the variable.

```
static void on_gathering_done(juice_agent_t *agent, void *user_ptr) {
    LOGI("on_gathering_done");

    char sdp[JUICE_MAX_SDP_STRING_LEN];
    juice_get_local_description(local_agent, sdp, JUICE_MAX_SDP_STRING_LEN);

    JNIEnv *env;
    jint res = (*java_vm)->GetEnv(java_vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    // is current thread known?
    if (res != JNI_OK) {
        LOGI("attaching current thread to VM");
        // not known, need to attach
        if ((*java_vm)->AttachCurrentThread(java_vm, &env, NULL) == JNI_OK) {

            jstring jstrBuf = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, sdp);
            (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, onCandidatesCallbackObj, onCandidatesCallback, jstrBuf);
            (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jstrBuf);

            (*java_vm)->DetachCurrentThread(java_vm);
        }
    } else {
        LOGI("thread already attached to VM");

        jstring jstrBuf = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, sdp);
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, onCandidatesCallbackObj, onCandidatesCallback, jstrBuf);
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jstrBuf);
    }
}
```

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Your JNI code is lacking all error checking. Every JNI call can pend an exception, and you need to check for that. Every time.

Comment: yes, I will add more checking, but what about the lifetime of Java variables when it's deleted immediately after the call to the Java method using that variable?

Comment: I provided a comment, not an answer. That's what comments are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your code line by line and think about memory management:

```
jstring jstrBuf = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, sdp);
```

This line creates a Java String object on the heap by copying from `sdp`. It only has one reference, namely the JNI-local reference here in `jstrBuf`.

```
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, onCandidatesCallbackObj, onCandidatesCallback, jstrBuf);
```

This line passes `jstrBuf` to your Java method. Method parameters are garbage collection roots, so there is an extra reference to your object from the call stack.

```
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jstrBuf);
```

This line removes your JNI-held local reference.
At this point either `setRemoteDescription` created an additional reference (eg by storing `sdp` somewhere or taking a substring of it, or it did not.

In the second case `jstrBuf` will no longer have references to it and the memory for it will be freed when the garbage collector runs again.

Comment: Thanks, I like the way you are working through this. So garbage collection will not start until the code returns from Java to NDK and it's DeleteLocalRef that starts this process. Thank you

Comment: To be precise: you have no control over _when_ garbage collection triggers. All DeleteLocalRef does is make the object _eligible_ for garbage collection.